# Difference between class and bean by @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-annotations

Recently, I tried to add a predefined Value with the @Value annotation to a Bean:

```
@Component
public class TaskletConfig {

  @Bean(name = "FilenameExecutionTasklet")
  @JobScope
  public Tasklet FilenameExecutionTasklet() {
      return new Tasklet() {

          @Value("#{jobParameters['inputFilename']}") 
          private String inputFilename;

          @Value("${platformImport.jobParameter.inputFile}") 
          private String inputFile;

          public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

              chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(inputFile , inputFilename);
              return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }

    };
  }
}
```

which ends up in a NullPointerException. If I do (almost) the same in a Tasklet, it works:

```
@JobScope
@Component
public class FilenameExecutionTasklet implements Tasklet {

  @Value("${platformImport.jobParameter.inputFile}")
  private String inputFile;

  @Value("#{jobParameters['inputFilename']}") 
  private String inputFilename;

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
      chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(inputFile, inputFilename);
      return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }
}
```

Could anybody, please, tell my why? I would have expect both working.

The value of `@Value("${platformImport.jobParameter.inputFile}")` is in the application.yml.

NPE is thrown in `chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(inputFile , inputFilename);` with `inputFile`.

Comment: On what line do you have NPE in the first example?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell: See edit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are hitting the NPE because late binding and order of evaluation within Spring Batch. Because the `FilenameExecutionTasklet` competent is in `JobScope`, it allows Spring Batch to evaluate other beans (those in singleton scope) in the application context BEFORE evaluating the `@Value` annotation.

I'm not positive on this, but you may be able to either add `@JobScope` to `TaskletConfig` or instead move the `@Value` annotations to be arguements to your bean creation method.

```
@Component
public class TaskletConfig {

  @Bean(name = "FilenameExecutionTasklet")
  @JobScope
  public Tasklet FilenameExecutionTasklet(
         @Value("#{jobParameters['inputFilename']}") String inputFilename,
         @Value("${platformImport.jobParameter.inputFile} String inputFile ) {

      return new Tasklet() {
          public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
              chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(inputFile , inputFilename);
              return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }

    };
  }

}
```

Outside of that, I'm just not quite sure what your use case is here. If the filename is being provided as a job parameter, what's the point of putting it in the execution context?

In fact the Tasklet will already have access to it via the `ChunkContext`:

```
public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution Contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    String fileName;
    //one way
    fileName = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getString("inputFileName");
    //another way
    fileName = (String) chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("inputFileName");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thx for your answer. Your first paragraph sounds reasonable. I am not that deep into spring batch to know what's beneath the surface of all these annotations. Unfortunately, your suggestion putting the @JobScope annotation to the ´TaskletConfig´ Level wasn't right. But, I didn't know that I can access the JobParameters in a similar way then the `ExecutionContext`. Thanks for that. (Reason for upvote.)

Comment: Interesting about the @JobScope placement not having an effect. Out of curiosity, did you also try moving the `@Value` properties to be arguments to the `FilenameExecutionTasklet()` method?